# quarkus return String

Tags: string, quarkus

```
 String s=  entityService.createEntry(multimaparr, resolved).onItem().transformToUni(createResult ->{
            String entityId = createResult.getEntityId();
        });
```

this is my code I want to return String like entityId but it is showing an error,
in the transform, is there any way to get String Entity Id in quarkus?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming createEntry() returns a reactive Mutiny type (i.e. Uni or Multi).

So lets say your createEntry() returns a Uni object, when you call .onItem(), that allows you to do something with the Entry object that will be emitted by the Uni. In your example you have transformToUni(); the parameter to that function should be a function that returns a Uni<?>. What you have provided is a function that returns void (i.e. there is no return). What you COULD do is have your code inside your lambda be:

```
String s = createResult.getEntityId();
return Uni.createFrom().item(s);
```

This would return a Uni to your transformToUni parameter.

You could do even one better by doing the following:

```
Uni<String> s = entityService.createEntry(multimaparr, resolved).onItem().transform(createResult -> createResult.getEntityId());
```

Now, how do you get the string out of your Uni? Two ways:

1. Fully embrace reactive types end-to-end. Assuming you're making an API, set the return type of you endpoint to be a Uni<?> where ? is whatever type you want to express
2. The [Uni Javadoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.smallrye.reactive/mutiny/latest/io.smallrye.mutiny/io/smallrye/mutiny/Uni.html) documents the "await" method. The return type of await() allows you to get the item emitted by the Uni by either waiting for a pre-determined amount of time (think of a timeout) or indefinitely (not recommended because of the halting problem).